# Extend onprepare protractor function

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have a onprepare function in my global protractor config

```
module.exports = {
.....
onPrepare: function() {
        //  At this point, global 'protractor' object will be set up, and jasmine
        //  will be available. For example, you can add a Jasmine reporter with:
        //      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(
        //          'outputdir/', true, true));
        var chai = require('chai'),
            chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
        global.chai = chai;
        global.expect = chai.expect;

        // setting up module file paths
        var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../');
        global.__paths = global.__paths || {};
        global.__paths.e2e = {
            parts: rootPath + 'parts',
            lib: rootPath + 'lib',
            pages: rootPath + 'pages',
            widgets: rootPath + 'widgets',
            api: rootPath + 'api',
        };

        // detect if this is running locally, or in some staging env
        global.isLocal = browser.baseUrl.indexOf('localhost') !== -1 ? true : false;
    }
};
```

I then have my protractor config extending this like so

```
var path = require('path');
var globalConf = require('global.protractor.conf.js');
exports.config = globalConf;
```

However I want to add some more paths to global.__paths.e2e  from this protractor.config however I am not sure how to extend the onPrepare function so that I can add couple more paths to it and still keep the original onprepare functionality

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure wheter this will work.can you please try the below method.

globalConf.onPrepare.global [key] = path